# Simple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is kind of awkward but I can't get the right sign of the solution of this integral:

$$\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_\alpha^1  \ln(1-x)dx$$

Change of variable:

$\cdot\ 1-x = t \rightarrow\ \fbox{$dx = -dt $}$,

$\cdot \ \alpha\leq x\leq 1 \rightarrow\ -1\leq -x\leq -\alpha\ \rightarrow\ 0\leq 1-x\leq 1-\alpha\ \rightarrow\ \fbox{ $0\leq t\leq 1-\alpha\ $}$

The integral becomes:

$$\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_\alpha^1  \ln(1-x)dx= \frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_0^{1-\alpha}  \ln(t)(-dt)=\frac{1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_0^{1-\alpha}  \ln(t)dt=$$

Integration by parts yields:

$$\frac{x\ln(x)}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\bigg|_0^{1-\alpha}-\frac{1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_0^{1-\alpha} dt = \frac{\ln(1-\alpha)-1}{\lambda}$$

while the correct solution has *opposite sign*. Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: You switched the interval, that means switching the sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x  =\alpha$ you have $t = 1 - \alpha$ and $x = 1 \implies t = 0$. Your integral becomes

$$-\int_{1-\alpha}^0 \ln t \,dt = \int_0^{1-\alpha} \ln t \, dt$$

Comment: I got that this was the problem, but I do not understand what is wrong with my reasoning: $\cdot \ \alpha\leq x\leq 1 \rightarrow\ -1\leq -x\leq -\alpha\ \rightarrow\ 0\leq 1-x\leq 1-\alpha\ \rightarrow\ \fbox{ $0\leq t\leq 1-\alpha\ $}$ and this should give me the integration extremals

Comment: That's what you get in the end, see last integral.

Comment: when I get that inequality $0\leq t\leq 1-\alpha$, I would use it to define the integration interval, so :
$\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_\alpha^1  \ln(1-x)dx = \frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_0^{1-\alpha}  \ln(t)(-dt)=\frac{1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_0^{1-\alpha}  \ln(t)dt $. Instead your change of variable says: $1-\alpha \leq t\leq 0$

Comment: You are not using the Change of Variable Theorem though. $$\int_{g(c)}^{g(d)} f(x) dx = \int _c^d f(g(t))g'(t) dt$$

Comment: Isn't that implied by : $dx=-dt$ ?

Comment: Also, don't forget the  integration limits.

Comment: In this case: $g(x) = x+\alpha$ with $g'(x)=1$ so that does not bring anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27018/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-mastro).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the integral becomes:
$$
\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_{1-\alpha}^0 = -\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_0^{1-\alpha}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\int_\alpha^1  \ln(1-x)dx=$$

---

Substitute $u=1-x$ and $du=-dx$ & $\{_{x=1}^{x=\alpha} \Longrightarrow  \{_{u=1-1=0}^{u=1-\alpha}$:

---

$$\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\left(-\int_{0}^{1-\alpha}1\cdot 1\ln(u)du\right)=$$

---

Use 'integrate by parts':

$v'=1 \Longrightarrow v=q$ &
$p'=\frac{1}{x} \Longrightarrow p=\ln(q)$

---

$$\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\left(-\left[u\ln(u)-x\right]_{0}^{1-\alpha}\right)=$$
$$\frac{-1}{\lambda(1-\alpha)}\left((\alpha-1)(\ln(1-\alpha)-1)\right)=$$
$$\frac{\ln(1-\alpha)-1}{\lambda}$$

Comment: the result should be : $\frac{1-\ln(1-\alpha)}{\lambda}$